# performance optimization for apache2 in case of multiusers

Tags: linux, flask, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I am using apache2 for the deployment of flask application on  Linux ubuntu20.04 platform by using mod_wsgi and after successful deployment when I tried to check the machine by giving the 5 users load and the machine crashed with error log 'Cannot retrieve the data and throw the message of "Services Unavailable"'

For the single user, apache is performing best but for multiuser, it crashes. how can I resolve this issue, your comments will be appreciated in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Flask by itself ( builtin server ) can only handle one request at a time.

You need to use e.g. `gunicorn`.

Also see the official documentation:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but same application when I deployed on windows IIS it is working fine the problem is with the load when I use two or three users apache is working fine but with the increase in the number of users there is major drop in performance ,in case of IIS it is performing well but apache is unable to handle

Comment: Without showing your Apache config, it is just guess work. And my best guess is, you configured Apache as reverse proxy on Flask, while Flask is run either via `flask run` or some `app.run()` command. As I already told you in the answer above, Flask itself is only able to handle 1 request at a time. That is why you get your "Service unavailable" message. You need to either configure Apache with `mod_wsgi` (where I cannot help), or you follow my advice and install and configure `gunicorn`. This works.

Comment: About why your IIS works different - again, you did not show any configuration. I can guess again. You configured IIS with wsgi or maybe IIS spawns several Flask instances, and thus is able to handle more than 1 request at a time. But this was not the original question. Also, you did not explain how you load tested your app. But once again, this does not matter as long as you do not configure your setup correctly.

Comment: I configured it by using WSGI modules, for clarification I deployed flask app on both Windows-based server and Apache Ubuntu to observe the performance, on ideal cases as Apache is much better in performance than IIS, it should show better results but it is showing the opposite so my question is why it is happening so either I should disable some modules within it or enable to increase the performance, I will share my apache config file if requires , thanks

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
  WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-path=/var/www/FlaskApp:/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
  <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn 
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Here is my apache conf file for flask app